# Autosaved form data in Google Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

A friend asked me that when we enter some information or data in a form and click a link (not submit but another link to open new page) in the website and then return back to the form, we can find this information entered for us.

Why do we not have this scenario in Internet Explorer or in Mozilla Firefox where we can return to the previous page with the last information  entered? Is it possible only on Google Chrome?